# A question about hypothesis testing on non normal distributions

Tags: hypothesis-testing, distributions, histogram

I have a set of 20 distributions (4 sets of 5) none of them are normally distributed but all are qualitatively similar and all have ~700k data points.

The images below are a typical example.

First a histogram using Sturge's rule for number of bins (68 here but that central spike is persistent upto a bin count of 700)

[image]

Secondly a box plot (without showing outliers)

[image]

Thirdly here's a box plot of one of the sets of 5.

[image]

Now my hypothesis is that the underlying phenomena (that the data is sampled from) would like to take the value 0.0 rather than any other value. This is where my technical ability in stats ends.

Given this kind of data how do I test my hypothesis quantitively?

Comment: "would like to take the value zero rather than any other value".  That could mean a few things...  It sounds like that means that the ***count*** of 0 would be [statistically] greater than... all other values combined? ... or, any other individual value?  But this only makes sense if your values are discrete.

Comment: @SalMangiafico that the count of 0 would be [statistically] greater than **any** other value

Comment: First thing to note is that with counts in the thousands, you are likely to find a statistically significant result.  You  will probably find after you run a couple of tests that it's silly to do so.  And that examining the counts in say a histogram or as a proportion will be more meaningful.

Comment: As long as there aren't too many unique values, I guess the approach I would use is calculate multi-nominal confidence intervals for each count, and then conclude that non-overlapping confidence intervals suggest statistically significant results.

Comment: Also, what is the meaning of having 4 "sets"? And of having multiple distributions of within the sets.  From what you presented, it looks like they're representing the same underlying population.